# Render image in django view with correct aspect ratios

Tags: jquery, python, django

I've got a model that takes images as follows

```
class CoverImage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image_upload = S3DirectField(upload_to='s3Direct')
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

It will accept images of any size and aspect ratio. Now, depending on where its being displayed, I want to render the image in my view with the correct aspect ratio. Currently the image is getting very distorted which is causing issues in displaying data.

I tried a JavaScript/Jquery solution as follows:

```
$('.main-img-ban').each(function(){ //main-img-ban is the image class
    var src = $(this).attr('src'); //getting external source
    var h=0, w=0; //initializing height and width
    $('<img />').attr('src', src).load(function(){ //getting the actual dimensions of the image
        h = this.height;
        w = this.width;
    });
    if (h>330){ //330 is max height of container for image
        var ratio = 330/h;
        $(this).css('height','330px');
        $(this).css('width',ratio*w);
        w = w*ratio;
        h = h*ratio;
    }
});
```

However, this isn't working correctly. Is there a way I can render the image correctly in my `views.py` file itself before sending it to the template? If yes, can someone point me in the right direction with some code examples?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. You said that you wish to correct the aspect ratio, yes? If so, then without cropping your image (or hiding parts of it) of course it will get distorted. Do you want cropping, or scaling? Or am I wrong entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 option. Either [resize image and save to directory and request specific size from view](http://davedash.com/2009/02/21/resizing-image-on-upload-in-django/) or resize image at rendering time. There is a app for resize image at render time called [imagefit](https://github.com/vinyll/django-imagefit). This allows you to render an image in a template and specify its dimensions. It preserves the original image file.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but this sounds like it could be very inefficient. Have you got any experience using imagefit in production on a large site. Currently we create and cache images - wondering if it's worth exploring this as a alternative

Comment: @AppHandwerker I would recommend you to look `easy-thumbnails` and `sorl-thumbnail`. I don't know why I have used `imagefit` at that time. It might be because, I was at the beginning of the professional programming on django at that time and might have found tutorial or snippet related to that library.

Comment: Appreciate you coming back. I get it. I mean it doesn't sound like a terrible idea if it caches it after the very 1st request (ever) - but it didn't sound like that. Will take a look at the other recommendations. Thanks for your time.